# Tomcat crashed with hs_error_pid*.log

Tags: java, tomcat6, jvm-crash

Our Tomcat 6.0.29 crashed this morning with the following error log. This is the first time  that I've seen such a log since the start of the server last year.

Can somebody tell me the reason for that?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006da3f79e, pid=3140, tid=484
#
# JRE version: 6.0_23-b05
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x24f79e]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000046e2800):  JavaThread "http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=484, stack(0x000000000c5e0000,0x000000000c620000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000000000000000

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x00000000046e2800, RCX=0x0000000000000280, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x000000000c61f790, RBP=0x000000000a0f05cd, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8=0x0000000000000032, R9=0x000000000a0f05cd, R10=0x0000000000000000, R11=0x00000000046e2800
R12=0x0000000000000032, R13=0x00000000bb8f2898, R14=0x000000000c61f930, R15=0x00000000046e2800
RIP=0x000000006da3f79e, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RBX=0x00000000046e2800
"http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000046e2800 nid=0x1e4 runnable [0x000000000c61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

RCX=0x0000000000000280
0x0000000000000280 is pointing to unknown location

RDX=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RSP=0x000000000c61f790
0x000000000c61f790 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000046e2800
"http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000046e2800 nid=0x1e4 runnable [0x000000000c61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

RBP=0x000000000a0f05cd
0x000000000a0f05cd is pointing to unknown location

RSI=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

RDI=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

R8 =0x0000000000000032
0x0000000000000032 is pointing to unknown location

R9 =0x000000000a0f05cd
0x000000000a0f05cd is pointing to unknown location

R10=0x0000000000000000
0x0000000000000000 is pointing to unknown location

R11=0x00000000046e2800
"http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000046e2800 nid=0x1e4 runnable [0x000000000c61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

R12=0x0000000000000032
0x0000000000000032 is pointing to unknown location

R13=0x00000000bb8f2898
{constMethod} 
 - klass: {other class}
 - method:       0x00000000bb8f28e0 {method} 'initIDs' '()V' in 'sun/nio/ch/ServerSocketChannelImpl'
 - exceptions:   0x00000000bae01ef8

R14=0x000000000c61f930
0x000000000c61f930 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000046e2800
"http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000046e2800 nid=0x1e4 runnable [0x000000000c61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

R15=0x00000000046e2800
"http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon prio=6 tid=0x00000000046e2800 nid=0x1e4 runnable [0x000000000c61f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE


Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000c61f790)
0x000000000c61f790:   00000000046e2800 0000000000000fc4
0x000000000c61f7a0:   00000000046e2800 000000000c61f920
0x000000000c61f7b0:   000000000c61f838 000000000c61f8b0
0x000000000c61f7c0:   0000000000000000 000000000c61f920
0x000000000c61f7d0:   00000000046e29c8 000000000c61f830
0x000000000c61f7e0:   0000000000000000 000000006d623215
0x000000000c61f7f0:   000000006de46520 000000000c61f918
0x000000000c61f800:   00000000046e29c8 0000000000000000
0x000000000c61f810:   00000000bb7569c0 00000000bd68b5c8
0x000000000c61f820:   0000000000000010 cd050f0af2f10002
0x000000000c61f830:   0000000000000000 00003cd1f5cd56fb
0x000000000c61f840:   0000000001c45440 00000000eb7d78a0
0x000000000c61f850:   00000000c09bab80 000000000c61f8f8
0x000000000c61f860:   00000000bb8f28a0 00000000011d12a0
0x000000000c61f870:   00000000c09bab40 00000000bcb0d840
0x000000000c61f880:   0000000000000001 00000000011c5b22 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000006da3f79e)
0x000000006da3f78e:   83 38 02 00 00 06 00 00 00 80 3d 2a ca 41 00 00
0x000000006da3f79e:   48 8b 16 74 17 44 8b 4a 08 0f b6 0d 0a b0 40 00 


Stack: [0x000000000c5e0000,0x000000000c620000],  sp=0x000000000c61f790,  free space=253k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x24f79e]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;[Ljava/net/InetSocketAddress;)I+0
J  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run()V
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000005528000 JavaThread "http-443-exec-65" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3168, stack(0x000000000c830000,0x000000000c870000)]
  0x0000000005529800 JavaThread "http-443-exec-64" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3192, stack(0x000000000c770000,0x000000000c7b0000)]
  0x000000000552b000 JavaThread "http-443-exec-59" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3592, stack(0x000000000d000000,0x000000000d040000)]
  0x0000000007f12800 JavaThread "http-80-9" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3952, stack(0x000000000cd80000,0x000000000cdc0000)]
  0x000000000a28b000 JavaThread "http-443-exec-41" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3844, stack(0x000000000c7f0000,0x000000000c830000)]
  0x0000000007f1b000 JavaThread "http-443-exec-40" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3452, stack(0x000000000c7b0000,0x000000000c7f0000)]
  0x000000000a287000 JavaThread "http-80-8" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3536, stack(0x000000000d500000,0x000000000d540000)]
  0x000000000a286800 JavaThread "http-80-7" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4064, stack(0x000000000d4c0000,0x000000000d500000)]
  0x000000000a285800 JavaThread "http-80-6" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3884, stack(0x000000000d480000,0x000000000d4c0000)]
  0x000000000a285000 JavaThread "http-80-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2008, stack(0x000000000d440000,0x000000000d480000)]
  0x000000000a284800 JavaThread "http-80-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3576, stack(0x000000000d400000,0x000000000d440000)]
  0x0000000007f14800 JavaThread "http-80-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1472, stack(0x000000000d3c0000,0x000000000d400000)]
  0x0000000007f14000 JavaThread "http-80-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2784, stack(0x000000000d380000,0x000000000d3c0000)]
  0x0000000007f19800 JavaThread "http-80-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3472, stack(0x000000000d340000,0x000000000d380000)]
  0x00000000046e6000 JavaThread "TP-Monitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2396, stack(0x000000000c720000,0x000000000c760000)]
  0x00000000046e5000 JavaThread "TP-Processor4" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3620, stack(0x000000000c6e0000,0x000000000c720000)]
  0x00000000046e4800 JavaThread "TP-Processor3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3828, stack(0x000000000c6a0000,0x000000000c6e0000)]
  0x00000000046e4000 JavaThread "TP-Processor2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2300, stack(0x000000000c660000,0x000000000c6a0000)]
  0x00000000046e3000 JavaThread "TP-Processor1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2720, stack(0x000000000c620000,0x000000000c660000)]
=>0x00000000046e2800 JavaThread "http-443-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=484, stack(0x000000000c5e0000,0x000000000c620000)]
  0x00000000046e1800 JavaThread "http-443-ClientPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2452, stack(0x000000000c5a0000,0x000000000c5e0000)]
  0x00000000046e1000 JavaThread "http-443-ClientPoller-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3096, stack(0x000000000c560000,0x000000000c5a0000)]
  0x00000000046e0000 JavaThread "http-80-Acceptor-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3720, stack(0x000000000c520000,0x000000000c560000)]
  0x0000000007f2c800 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1624, stack(0x000000000c4e0000,0x000000000c520000)]
  0x0000000007f2a800 JavaThread "scheduler_QuartzSchedulerThread" [_thread_blocked, id=3084, stack(0x000000000cc80000,0x000000000ccc0000)]
  0x0000000007f29800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-10" [_thread_blocked, id=2080, stack(0x000000000cc40000,0x000000000cc80000)]
  0x0000000007f29000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-9" [_thread_blocked, id=2240, stack(0x000000000cc00000,0x000000000cc40000)]
  0x0000000007f28000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-8" [_thread_blocked, id=1376, stack(0x000000000cbc0000,0x000000000cc00000)]
  0x0000000007f27800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-7" [_thread_blocked, id=3436, stack(0x000000000cb80000,0x000000000cbc0000)]
  0x0000000007f26800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-6" [_thread_blocked, id=3804, stack(0x000000000cb40000,0x000000000cb80000)]
  0x0000000007f26000 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-5" [_thread_blocked, id=3324, stack(0x000000000cb00000,0x000000000cb40000)]
  0x0000000007f25800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-4" [_thread_blocked, id=3664, stack(0x000000000cac0000,0x000000000cb00000)]
  0x0000000005311800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=2096, stack(0x000000000ca80000,0x000000000cac0000)]
  0x000000000615a800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=3808, stack(0x000000000ca40000,0x000000000ca80000)]
  0x0000000008568800 JavaThread "scheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2724, stack(0x000000000ca00000,0x000000000ca40000)]
  0x000000000499a800 JavaThread "NioBlockingSelector.BlockPoller-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3852, stack(0x00000000064a0000,0x00000000064e0000)]
  0x0000000004912800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=856, stack(0x0000000006460000,0x00000000064a0000)]
  0x0000000004605800 JavaThread "Thread-2" [_thread_in_native, id=3872, stack(0x0000000004c00000,0x0000000004c40000)]
  0x0000000004658800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2212, stack(0x0000000004b80000,0x0000000004bc0000)]
  0x0000000000f27800 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2964, stack(0x00000000045a0000,0x00000000045e0000)]
  0x0000000000f23800 JavaThread "CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1928, stack(0x0000000004560000,0x00000000045a0000)]
  0x0000000000f1b000 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2120, stack(0x0000000004520000,0x0000000004560000)]
  0x0000000000f19800 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4056, stack(0x00000000044e0000,0x0000000004520000)]
  0x0000000000f19000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1464, stack(0x00000000044a0000,0x00000000044e0000)]
  0x0000000000eb2000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4076, stack(0x0000000004460000,0x00000000044a0000)]
  0x0000000000eb1800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3132, stack(0x0000000004420000,0x0000000004460000)]
  0x00000000006d2800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=2944, stack(0x00000000007d0000,0x0000000000810000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000000eaf000 VMThread [stack: 0x00000000043e0000,0x0000000004420000] [id=392]
  0x0000000000f72800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000004bc0000,0x0000000004c00000] [id=2872]

VM state:synchronizing (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000006d14c0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000000eaf000
[0x00000000006d19c0] Heap_lock - owner thread: 0x0000000007f2c800

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 138496K, used 23348K [0x00000000eaab0000, 0x00000000fa570000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 22016K, 100% used [0x00000000eaab0000,0x00000000ec030000,0x00000000ec030000)
  from space 116480K, 1% used [0x00000000ec030000,0x00000000ec17d300,0x00000000f31f0000)
  to   space 116480K, 0% used [0x00000000f33b0000,0x00000000f33b0000,0x00000000fa570000)
 PSOldGen        total 699072K, used 699071K [0x00000000c0000000, 0x00000000eaab0000, 0x00000000eaab0000)
  object space 699072K, 99% used [0x00000000c0000000,0x00000000eaaaffe8,0x00000000eaab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 69952K, used 69633K [0x00000000bae00000, 0x00000000bf250000, 0x00000000c0000000)
  object space 69952K, 99% used [0x00000000bae00000,0x00000000bf200608,0x00000000bf250000)

Dynamic libraries:
0x0000000000400000 - 0x0000000000416000     C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\bin\tomcat6.exe
0x0000000077ec0000 - 0x0000000077ffc000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000077d40000 - 0x0000000077eb3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x0000000077c20000 - 0x0000000077d2c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007ff7fc90000 - 0x000007ff7fd2c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007ff7fee0000 - 0x000007ff7ffe6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007ff7fd30000 - 0x000007ff7fed0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x000007ff7e9c0000 - 0x000007ff7e9e2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x000007ff7fc00000 - 0x000007ff7fc86000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007ff7f190000 - 0x000007ff7fb9c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x000007ff7ef60000 - 0x000007ff7effb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007ff7d500000 - 0x000007ff7d539000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007ff7f000000 - 0x000007ff7f187000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.3790.4770_x-ww_3807D667\comctl32.dll
0x000000006d7f0000 - 0x000000006dee0000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007ff7e240000 - 0x000007ff7e290000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x000007ff77100000 - 0x000007ff7710b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rdpsnd.dll
0x000007ff7d4d0000 - 0x000007ff7d4ea000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSTA.dll
0x000007ff77370000 - 0x000007ff77409000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NETAPI32.dll
0x000007ff7e380000 - 0x000007ff7e390000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x000000006d760000 - 0x000000006d76e000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x000000006d3b0000 - 0x000000006d3d7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x000000006d310000 - 0x000000006d31a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x000000006d7b0000 - 0x000000006d7c2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x000000006d600000 - 0x000000006d617000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x000007ff77310000 - 0x000007ff77340000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007ff77140000 - 0x000007ff7714c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x000007ff771b0000 - 0x000007ff7722d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x000007ff7e8f0000 - 0x000007ff7e93f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007ff7e9f0000 - 0x000007ff7e9fb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007ff7e950000 - 0x000007ff7e9b6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x000007ff7ea00000 - 0x000007ff7ea07000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000000006d540000 - 0x000000006d54a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\management.dll
0x0000000068000000 - 0x000000006804c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007ff6d200000 - 0x000007ff6d293000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x000007ff77170000 - 0x000007ff7717b000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000000006d620000 - 0x000000006d62b000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\endorsed -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\temp -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Tomcat 6.0\conf\logging.properties -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=US vfprintf -Xms128m -Xmx1024m 
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23
PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\The Open Group\WMI Mapper\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_23\bin
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 16 Model 8 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows Server 2003 family Build 3790 Service Pack 2

CPU:total 2 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 16 model 8 stepping 0, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, popcnt, mmxext, 3dnow, 3dnowext, lzcnt, sse4a

Memory: 4k page, physical 2096476k(60588k free), swap 3537116k(1516660k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (19.0-b09) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.6.0_23-b05), built on Nov 13 2010 02:43:42 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 8.0 (VS2005)

time: Thu Sep 20 07:17:51 2012
elapsed time: 137846 seconds
```

Comment: It's hard to diagnose these problems. One thing I'd do is upgrade the JDK, because you're using a pretty old version (and newer versions include both bugfixes and security fixes).

Comment: It's probably a JVM/JRE bug, with an attempt to read address `0x0000000000000000` (i.e. a real NULL pointer).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I'll take care of this issue for the next days, but I'll guess and hope it is pretty unsual. Perhaps an upgrade would be the best.